# How can import custom js file from assets on vue js?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

How can import custom js file from assets on vue js?

I try this;

```
<script src="./assets/js/dragging.js"></script>
```

But that's code not working.

Comment: "assets" folder is for files which will be processed by webpack. Use "static" folder for files that you want to include statically. If you still want to use the assets folder you would need to `import` the script. http://vuejs-templates.github.io/webpack/static.html

Comment: There's not a whole lot of context here to help. Given the path structure, are you using vue in Laravel? Are you using vue-cli or webpack?

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
import ClassName from "src/Filename";
</script>
```

Comment: Please read [answer] and [edit] your answer to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post.